# How to write URL as filename?

Tags: r, filenames

I would like to use the URL address as filename instead of "i". Thought it was piece of cake with just `links[i,0]` instead of "i" in the write function, but it does not seem to work.

```
library(RCurl) 
library(foreach) 
library(foreign)

links <- read.table("CSV FILE WITH N LINKS", header = T, quote = "\"")

outpath <- "RANDOM FOLDER"

foreach(i = 1:nrow(links)) %do% {
text <- getURL(links[i,])  print(i) 
write(as.character(text), file = paste(outpath, "/", i, ".txt", sep = ""))}
```

I get the following error:

```
10: In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file '/Users/kasper2304/Desktop/Lego test/Star Wars output/http://news.lugnet.com/starwars/?n=10.txt': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what kind of object `links` is, but perhaps your confusion is that R is a 1-indexed language, not a 0-indexed language, so all indices begin at 1.

Comment: Maybe: `write(as.character(text), file = paste(outpath,"/", links[i]".txt",sep=""))`

Comment: if this were reproducible and you gave us more information about what "does not work" meant, you might get an answer quite quickly ...

Comment: links is a vector of URL's in csv format. I am loading in the csv file and the code extracts the different URL's as separate .txt files...

links[i] just gives me a file named "c(1,...,n)"...

Comment: Have provided you with more code now. Hope that helps.

Comment: OK, so `read.table` return a data frame, which is multidimensional, not a vector, which is one dimensional. You might want to get the differences between those basic data types sorted out first before you proceed.

Comment: I have come to think that it might simply be because iOS does to accept ":" as a character in filename. So the problem might simply be solved by cutting "http://" away form the URL and using the rest as the filename.

Comment: I'd say that's your issue.  You write it as a solution and mark it as correct.

Comment: How can this be an R question if the problem lies with "iOS"? The Mac version of R does not exist on iOS! Can we get the terminology a bit more precise?

Comment: To begin with I thought it was an R problem but having played around and thought about the ":" issue in filenames (it is the same with windows) it came clear to me that that was the problem. So you are right that it is not really an R problem and more a general problem. Maybe you would actually say that it is not a regular problem, just a thing that newbies like my need to be aware of.

Comment: DWin: I have changed the title as well as the tag. Does that satisfy you? iOS should simply just have been OS. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Post your "Solution" as an answer instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: Can people who down voted this question please let me know why they downvoted it as the question has been answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:` is not accepted as a character in a filename in either Windows or Mac OS. Remove the `:` character from the filename to solve the problem. One might use `strsplit()` for that purpose.

Comment: What would that change the filename to?

Comment: Cool. Will experiment with that and post it if i come up with a better solution.